# Amazon SES 554 message rejected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ses

I'm getting an error when trying to send email from my application.

It's configured in Elastic Beanstalk so I created a CNAME myapp.mydomain.com

My application sets the universal from address to noreply@myapp.mydomain.com.

host email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com[52.24.143.150] said: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: noreply@myapp.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com (in reply to end of DATA command))
As you can see my MAIL FROM address changes to the beanstalk hostname and rejects it.

I'm out of the sandbox

I tried to verify noreply@myapp.mydomain.com. It auto verified but I still got the error.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you try https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-554-400-message-rejected-error/?nc1=h_ls ?

Comment: Also this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/request-production-access.html

Comment: @pedro_bb7 Thanks for this. It looks like during the mail relay the hostname changes. I'm not sure what process is doing it though